# How do I increase my auto population range further in my Excel VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to increase the columns that auto populate from the manual entry section D4:G13 into the below table from 14 columns which works now, and increase to 18 columns, as I have expanded the manual entry section recently.

Any attempt to increase the range within the below code is bringing up the error you see in the picture below. It is highligthing the code line with with * I have marked below.

So how do I increase it to 18?

I have removed all merged lines and condensed the table. I don't feel there is many options left for me to, but to expand the code.

Thanks all for help.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Booking_Load()
With Sheet5
    Dim BkgRow As Long
    Dim BkgCol As Long
    If .range("B1").Value = Empty Then Exit Sub
    BkgRow = .range("B1").Value
    .range("B2").Value = False 'Set New Booking to False
    .range("B3").Value = True 'Set Booking Load to True
    *** For BkgCol = 4 To 14 ***
    *** .range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).Value = .Cells(BkgRow, BkgCol).Value ***'Load Booking Details
    Next BkgCol
    .Shapes("NewBkgGrp").Visible = msoFalse
    .Shapes("ExistBkgGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
    .range("B3").Value = False  'Set Booking Load to False
End With
End Sub

Sub Booking_SaveUpdate()
With Sheet5
    Dim BkgRow As Long
    Dim BkgCol As Long
    If .range("B2").Value = True Then 'New Booking
        BkgRow = .range("D999").End(xlUp).Row + 1  'First available Row
    Else: 'Existing Booking
        BkgRow = .range("B1").Value 'Booking Row
    End If
    * For BkgCol = 4 To 14 *
      * .Cells(BkgRow, BkgCol).Value = .range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).Value *   'Save Booking Details
    Next BkgCol
        .Shapes("NewBkgGrp").Visible = msoFalse
        .Shapes("ExistBkgGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
        .range("B2").Value = False 'Set New Booking to False
        .range("B3").Value = False 'Set Booking Load to False
End With
End Sub
```

### -

-
Updated images from your request @Zac 15:48 - 14-01-20

[[image: ]]

[[image: ]]

Comment: What is the error in your picture? I suggest you read [mcve].

Comment: Are you sure that `Sheet5` is **Diary Entry** sheet? When you added the columns, did you replace the old sheet with a new one? Try changing your `With Sheet5` statement to: `With Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Diary Entry")`

Comment: @zac Thank you! this has solved the issue, it defintiely was sheet5 I was opertaing on, according to excel objects list for sheets. So not sure why it would have a reference that isn't releative as I didn't take data from other sheets numbers?

Comment: @SJR Not quite sure how I was supposed to present, if added too much detail, sorry for that, next time, and I'm sure there will be a next time I will produce more minimal example for your eyes.

Comment: @Zac That seemed to of worked for the loading the details back into the manual entry frame for editing purposes, but on testing, creating a new booking and then when trying to save details, the save button does nothing what so ever now, even if changing the values back to normal?

```With Sheet5
    If .range("B2").Value = True Then 'New Booking
        BkgRow = .range("D999").End(xlUp).Row + 1  'First available Row```
-
```For BkgCol = 4 To 14
      .range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).Value = .Cells(BkgRow, BkgCol).Value```

Comment: No worries, just that the more "noise" you can filter out the easier it is for others to discern the problem or even replicate your set up.

Comment: Did you try making the same change in `Booking_SaveUpdate`? I'm presuming that this UDF does the save?

Comment: @Zac I did do both sets of code, the load details and save updates UDFS? without any luck, I tried to change it back to the point of save working, but without any joy so far.

Comment: Is it not working for either the new booking or existing booking? or is it working for one but not the other? if so, which one works and which doesn't?

Comment: @Zac Yes, I trialled both the exisiting and new options to save details and neither is working. The only thing of note from the test was that when I have an existing booking selected and press save, the selected cell pings over to S4 range, which is the Check out date range.

Comment: When `BkgCol` variable has a value of 13, it should throw an error as row 14: col 13 (P14) has no value. I'm surprised you are not getting any errors. Can you post your updated code without the `*`. I cannot recreate your sheet but can go through the updated code

Comment: @Zac, I've updated the original post with a picture of the sheet it's self and also a picture of the code with the error line highlighted. Error code is now "1004 application-defined or object-defined error"

Comment: The line that you have the arrow on is writing the date from your row to the fields that you populate. Swap it around: change it to: `.Cells(BkgRow, BkgCol).Value = .range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).Value`. Also, you have it set so that you are working on an existing case but `B1` has no value

Comment: @Zac, genius, must of happened when I was editig it earlier for the original problem!
VBA is so unforgiving for newbies! everything is working fine now, thanks very much. Oh and by the way when the row is selected in the table, B1 populates with the row number automatically. There is a lot of code that I couldnt show you as to minimise confusion!

Comment: :) we've all done it. VBA is a bit unforgiving. Glad it helped

Answer (score 0):

Let's Change

```
  For BkgCol = 4 To 14 
      .range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).Value = .Cells(BkgRow, BkgCol).Value
 Next BkgCol
```

to

```
 For BkgCol = 4 To 14 
     .range(.Cells(BkgRow, BkgCol).Value).value = .range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).value 
     '=> .range("D24").value = .range(.Cells(14, 4).Value).value
 Next BkgCol
```

both procedures. May be... ~ ;)

If I think wrong, then maybe the error is because cell P14 is blank so

```
.range(.Cells(14, BkgCol).Value).Value = .range(blank).value => Error
```

Comment: Thanks for helping GridLock,  I did try this, unfortunately it crashed my book once and then on trying again it was populating the table instead of the entry area. Changing the sheet reference from 5 to active sheet seemed to have solved the problem. :)